# for loops and matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I am trying to link two equations, where I use a for loop calculate the value of k from the range of frequencies (eg. 1-5 Hz) then use each of the k values and substitute the values of k into a 6x6 matrix. Can anyone help show me how to create a matrix for each value of k in Matlab?

**1st Equation**

```
for f = 1:5; % Range of Frequencies (Hz)

f;
w = 2.*pi.*f; % Angular Frequency (Hz)

p = 8050;% Density of Mild Steel(kg/m^3)

v = 0.30; % Poissons Ratio of Mild Steel

R = 0.02; % Radius of Pipe (m)

E = 210*10^9; % Youngs Modulus of Mild Steel (pa)

a = (w.^2).*p;

b = (p.*(1-(v.^2)).*(R.^2).*(w.^2)-E);

c = (p.*(R.^2).*(w.^2)-E).*E;

**k(f) = sqrt((a.*b)/c); % k = Wave Number**

end
```

**2nd Equation (6x6 Matrix)**

```
k = 

L1=0.1;
L2=0.6;
L3=0.6;



 D= [0,0,exp(-k*L1),exp(-k*L2),0,0; exp(-k*L1),1,exp(-k*L1),exp(-k*L2),0,0; -k*exp(-k*L1),k,k*exp(-k*L1),-k*exp(-k*L2),0,0;0,0,exp(-k*(L1+L2)),k,-exp(-k*(L1+L2)),-exp(-k*L3);0,0,-k*exp(-k*(L1+L2)),1,k*exp(-k*(L1+L2)),k*exp(-k*L3);0,0,exp(-k*(L1+L2)),1,0,0]
```

Comment: Would be possible to rephrase your question? What do you mean that you substitute the values of K? You change the values of K? And how you would create a 6x6 matrix from the K values? randomly? By a specific pattern? What you need help on?

Comment: I think i need to use 'for loops' to find k for each value of f, then substitute the k values into the matrix D

for example:

when f=1:5, calculate k for every value of f

which gives:
f=1, k=0.0012

f=2, k = 0.0025

f=3, k=0.0037

f=4, k=0.0049

f=5, k= 0.0062

Substitute k and L1,L2,L3 into the D matrix

then end result is 5 matrices

Answer (score 0):

(Answer modified following the comment)

You can try definig the output array `D` as a 3 dimensions array.

```
D=NaN(6,6,length(k))
for i=1:length(k)
   D(:,:,i)= [0,0,exp(-k(i)*L1),exp(-k(i)*L2),0,0; exp(-k(i)*L1),1,exp(-k(i)*L1),exp(-k(i)*L2),0,0; -k(i)*exp(-k(i)*L1),k(i),k(i)*exp(-k(i)*L1),-k(i)*exp(-k(i)*L2),0,0;0,0,exp(-k(i)*(L1+L2)),k(i),-exp(-k(i)*(L1+L2)),-exp(-k(i)*L3);0,0,-k(i)*exp(-k(i)*(L1+L2)),1,k(i)*exp(-k(i)*(L1+L2)),k(i)*exp(-k(i)*L3);0,0,exp(-k(i)*(L1+L2)),1,0,0]
end
```

The `D` array will be:

```
D(:,:,1) =

         0         0    0.9999    0.9993         0         0
    0.9999    1.0000    0.9999    0.9993         0         0
   -0.0012    0.0012    0.0012   -0.0012         0         0
         0         0    0.9991    0.0012   -0.9991   -0.9993
         0         0   -0.0012    1.0000    0.0012    0.0012
         0         0    0.9991    1.0000         0         0


D(:,:,2) =

         0         0    0.9998    0.9985         0         0
    0.9998    1.0000    0.9998    0.9985         0         0
   -0.0025    0.0025    0.0025   -0.0025         0         0
         0         0    0.9983    0.0025   -0.9983   -0.9985
         0         0   -0.0025    1.0000    0.0025    0.0025
         0         0    0.9983    1.0000         0         0


D(:,:,3) =

         0         0    0.9996    0.9978         0         0
    0.9996    1.0000    0.9996    0.9978         0         0
   -0.0037    0.0037    0.0037   -0.0037         0         0
         0         0    0.9974    0.0037   -0.9974   -0.9978
         0         0   -0.0037    1.0000    0.0037    0.0037
         0         0    0.9974    1.0000         0         0


D(:,:,4) =

         0         0    0.9995    0.9971         0         0
    0.9995    1.0000    0.9995    0.9971         0         0
   -0.0049    0.0049    0.0049   -0.0049         0         0
         0         0    0.9966    0.0049   -0.9966   -0.9971
         0         0   -0.0049    1.0000    0.0049    0.0049
         0         0    0.9966    1.0000         0         0


D(:,:,5) =

         0         0    0.9994    0.9963         0         0
    0.9994    1.0000    0.9994    0.9963         0         0
   -0.0061    0.0062    0.0061   -0.0061         0         0
         0         0    0.9957    0.0062   -0.9957   -0.9963
         0         0   -0.0061    1.0000    0.0061    0.0061
         0         0    0.9957    1.0000         0         0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but if you copy and paste the **2nd equation** into matlab and give k a value eg. k=0.0012,

it creates a 6x6 matrix. I am unable to post an image because I have only just signed up.

Comment: I did not understand your question; following your comment, i modified the answer. Hope, now, I've understood the question.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer your question...

Firstly, you **don't** need the initial for loop. You can calculate all values of wavelength without loops.

```
f = 1:5; % Range of Frequencies (Hz)
w = 2.*pi.*f; % Angular Frequency (Hz)
p = 8050;% Density of Mild Steel(kg/m^3)
v = 0.30; % Poissons Ratio of Mild Steel
R = 0.02; % Radius of Pipe (m)
E = 210*10^9; % Youngs Modulus of Mild Steel (pa)
a = (w.^2).*p;
b = (p.*(1-(v.^2)).*(R.^2).*(w.^2)-E);
c = (p.*(R.^2).*(w.^2)-E).*E;
k = sqrt((a.*b)./c); % k = Wave Number
L1=0.1;
L2=0.6;
L3=0.6;
```

Then you can use a for loop to calculate the D matrix and a cell array to store the results:

```
results = cell(1, length(k));
for i = 1:length(k)
    results{i} = [
                      0,0,exp(-k(i)*L1),exp(-k(i)*L2),0,0;...
                      exp(-k(i)*L1),1,exp(-k(i)*L1),exp(-k(i)*L2),0,0;...
                      -k(i)*exp(-k(i)*L1),k(i),k(i)*exp(-k(i)*L1),-k(i)*exp(-k(i)*L2),0,0;...
                      0,0,exp(-k(i)*(L1+L2)),k(i),-exp(-k(i)*(L1+L2)),-exp(-k(i)*L3);...
                      0,0,-k(i)*exp(-k(i)*(L1+L2)),1,k(i)*exp(-k(i)*(L1+L2)),k(i)*exp(-k(i)*L3);...
                      0,0,exp(-k(i)*(L1+L2)),1,0,0
                     ]
end
```

P.S. Without trying to get on to you, I think that what you just want is to someone solve an excercise for you. If this is not the case, ignore my p.s.

Comment: Thank you, this is the exact format I was trying to achieve. Haha cheers but this is no exercise